# Terminal shows only blocks

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

I'm running Arch Linux, and I just did a `sudo pacman -Syu`. Now when I open a gnome-terminal or an xfce4-terminal, all I see are blocks.

[image: terminal full of blocks]

I'm totally clueless what's going on, or what has caused this. Thankfully, xterm still shows everything properly, so I can run commands.

Here is the pacman log of the last update if it helps: https://pastebin.com/raw/8GeUZfat

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use another font? Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Reboot, yes... Another font, no.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion. A bunch of fonts are showing up as blocks, but some of them work. Changing to a working font fixes the problem.

Comment: Try `fc-cache -f`

Comment: See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/386

Comment: I see `upgraded pango (1:1.43.0-2 -> 1:1.44.1-1)` in my pacman log, so it is that issue for sure. I won't bother to downgrade pango, as I'm happy to simply use a different font; but imo this issue should never have propagated all the way up to an end user like me. Customary xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1172/.